# mapping surjective not injective

Tags: functions

I have to construct a mapping from [0, 1] to [0, 1] that is surjective but not injective. I nailed it down to four different possibilities:

[image]

[image]

I am searching for a function that discribes this mapping.

For the opposite (mapping from [0, 1] to [0, 1] that is injective but not surjective) an example would be the `ln(x)`.

EDIT: As pointed out by 5xum it seems that I got the task wrong and it is in fact asked for the range [0, 1] and not a set with the elements 0 and 1. Sorry for he confusion.

Comment: For injective, but not surjective, taking any $x$ and sending it to $x/2$ works fine. The logarithm is definitely not what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you mean $\{0,1\}$ or $[0,1]$? Because your text says $[0,1]$, but your pictures show $\{0,1\}$

Comment: Note that what you have written down aren't even functions. Functions by definition only have $1$ output, so saying $0\mapsto0$ *and* $0\mapsto1$ is nonsensical. That being said, if your set is $\{0,1\}$, there is **no** surjective, noninjective map. If your set is the interval $[0,1]$, on the other hand, certain variants of trig. functions might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After being enlightened about my misunderstanding concerning sets and ranges in this question, I want to answer it myself:

For a function from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ that is injective but not surjective I would go with the suggestion of Arthur use $f(x) = \frac x 2$ as an example.

For a function from $[0, 1]$ to $[0, 1]$ that is surjective but not injective I found $f(x) = \frac {sin(2 \cdot \pi \cdot x)}{2} + 0.5$

Comment: Also: $x\mapsto 4x(1-x)$.